# how to assign failover ip into windows vm (ubuntu, kvm)

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-14.04, failover, dedicated-server

I purchased a dedicate server (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64) with a failover ip from online.net. And i want to setup a windows vm with failover ip using kvm. I tried myself several times, but all failed. Any one could tell me how to do this? Because of my poor english and low linux knowledge, please describe steps as much detail as possible.

> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
> auto em1
> iface em1 inet dhcp
>
> iface em1 inet6 static
> address 2001:0bc8:xxxx::1
> netmask 48
> accept_ra 1
> pre-up dhclient -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf -pf /run/dhclient6.em1.pid -6 -P > em1
> pre-down dhclient -x -pf /run/dhclient6.em1.pid
>
> auto em1:0
> iface em1:0 inet static
> address 212.129.62.xxx
> netmask 255.255.255.255

Comment: http://blog.alteroot.org/articles/2013-09-06/setup-kvm-libvirt-sur-dedibox.html

Comment: french is too difficult to me...anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: You don't speak French? You probably should have mentioned that :) Many online.net customers do...

Comment: yeah, i forget do this...